# How to set a execution time only for a php file?

Tags: php, ajax, comet

a comet project.
I want the comet server(a php file) is executed forever and other php file follow the rules that setted by the php.ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  the [set_time_limit()](http://us.php.net/set_time_limit) function.